# difference between render and reRender attributes in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What is the Difference between render and reRender attribute in jSf. Can we use reRender with JSf Core library or it can be used only with ajax4Jsf library.what are the function of both?.

Comment: There is no `reRender` attribute in JSF. It's part of Rich Faces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<f:ajax event="change" render=":moons :suns" />    
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender=":moons, :suns" />   
<p:ajax event="change" update=":moons, :suns" />
```

---

**1.** Note those three ajax calls. The first one is a standard JSF `ajax` that belongs to `java.sun.com/jsf/core` it uses `renders` attribute to update the required components in DOM.

**render** - *A space-separated list of IDs for components that will be updated after an Ajax request.* (only spaces are valid)

---

**2.** The second one belongs to RichFaces 3, note the difference on `event` attribute

**reRender** - *attribute that defines id(s) of JSF component(s) that should be rerendered after an Ajax request. ... It's also possible to use JSF EL expression as a value of the reRender attribute. It might be a property of types Set, Collection, Array or simple String.* (commas are valid, not sure about spaces)

- in RichFaces 4 the `reRender` attribute has been renamed to `render`

---

**3.** The third one belongs to PrimeFaces and uses an `update` attribute (in my opinion the most meaningful name of those three)

**update** - *Component(s) to update with ajax.* (spaces and commas are valid)

---

So as you can see they basically do the same job with minor differences in how to use them. No, You can't mix them. Use `render` with jsf/core, `reRender` with ajax4Jsf in Richfaces 3, and `update` with PrimeFaces components. Note that in RichFaces 4 the `reRender` attribute has been renamed to `render`.

What concerns events - PrimeFaces and jsf/core use actual DOM-event names (unprefixed), RichFaces on the other hand uses prefixed events eg. `onchange` as opposed to `change`. Note that the new RichFaces 4(`<a4j:ajax>` replaced `<a4j:support>`) `<a4j:ajax>`'s `event` attribute works the same as `<f:ajax>`'s `event`.