# Which render event should be used when replacing a4j:support with f:ajax tags?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, ajax4jsf

Using [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) and [Migrating JSF 1.1 with Ajax4jsf 1.x to JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553033/migrating-jsf-1-1-with-ajax4jsf-1-x-to-jsf-2) as guides to upgrade some JSP files to Facelets, I came across some `a4j:support` tags nested inside `h:commandLink` components in those JSP files, like this:

```
<h:commandLink action="someAction" title="#{someTitle}">
    ...
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="someId"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Going by the links mentioned above, I changed this in my Facelet to:

```
<h:commandLink action="someAction" title="#{someTitle}">
    ...
    <f:ajax event="change" render="someId"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

but this lead to some JSF error about the `change` event not being supported in the `h:commandLink` component.

Trying to use the advice from [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag), I checked the [documentation of h:commandLink](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html) and it turned out that `onchange` is indeed not among the attributes of `h:commandLink`.

So, my question now is: which of the attributes available in `h:commandLink` should be used in the Facelet's `event` attribute to keep the functionality of the `a4j:support event="onchange"` tag in my old JSP file?

Comment: remove the event attribute from `f:ajax` and use update `instead` of `render`

Comment: Do you want to update ID on link click or action complete?

Comment: @500Servererror From the official documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html) it looks like there is no `update` attribute in the `f:ajax` tag. Do you mean the `p:ajax` tag from the PrimeFaces library? Going by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383573/difference-between-render-and-rerender-attributes-in-jsf, it looks like `p:ajax` has the `update` attribute, but we are not using PrimeFaces.

Comment: @scholt right... sorry. try removing the event attribute and keeping the render one... any luck? I've been using PrimeFaces more extensively that's why I didn't suggest it as an answer but just commented hehe

Comment: @VasilLukach I guess I want to update `someId` on a click, not on a completed action, at least that's how I interpret the `onchange` event of the `a4j:support` tag currently in use. I suppose I should take the `click` event in the `f:ajax` tag in my Facelet, then.

Comment: For click on link you can use `<p:ajax event="click" .../>